# Symfony 2.1 - injecting entity_manager to services.yml

Tags: php, symfony, service

I'm trying to inject the entity_manager to my service but, whatever I try it doesn't work. Thera are some different approaches on the web, so which is the correct?

```
services:
menu:
    class: AppBundle\Service\Menu
    arguments:    ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
```

or

```
services:
menu:
    class: AppBundle\Service\Menu
    arguments:    [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
```

both don't work and give me a

*The file "D:\xamp\htdocs\icp\app/config\services.yml" does not contain valid YAML*

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Watch out for spaces. With YAML they are very important.

```
services:
    menu:
        class: AppBundle\Service\Menu
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
```

Comment: tanks!! that was it :)